# destroy angular $scope variable and clear its bind data in DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a single page application and due to memory leak issue i want to clear the angular `data-bind` in HTML DOM.

I have tried many things like:

- clear DOM while Bootstrap Modal Close event.
- angular $destroy method

but still i have a memory leak issue. How can I fix it?

// Code call on modal close Event

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("MyAngularControllerDivID")).scope();  
scope.$destroy();
```

//$destroy

```
  $scope.$on("$destroy",function() {  
        $(window).off( "resize.Viewport" );  
        $("#MyAngularControllerDivID").parent().empty();  
        removejscssfile(List of js or css,"js");  
    });
```

Comment: can you provide more code any fiddle with more of your code

Comment: Possibly this article will help to understand whot is the problem
http://www.mattzeunert.com/2014/11/03/manually-removing-angular-directives.html

Comment: thanx Vitalii for replying. I have already implemented $destroy. but don't know why its not removing Nodes from HTML DOM which are bind by angular.